# Multiplicação entre dois vetores para uma soma final em Java

Tags: java

Gostaria de realizar uma multiplicação entre dois vetores, cada qual com seu respectivo correspondente, como posso exemplificar abaixo:

```
i = [a1, a2, a3, ...]
j = [b1, b2, b3, ...]
```

Poderia me resultar um terceiro vetor, como este:

```
i x j = [a1*b1, a2*b2, a3*b3, ...]
```

Explico a vocês o por que disto, pois ao final desta operação, gostaria de somar todos os componentes deste vetor.

A aplicação do código será para que o usuário forneça tamanhos (milímetros) em um vetor, e quantidade (peças) noutro vetor, assim preciso que haja a multiplicação para obter a quantidade linear total do produto e no final a quantidade linear de tudo que foi fornecido.

O código que pensei segue abaixo:

```
    int n = 5; 
    int comprimento_vetor[] = new int[n]; 
    int i = 0;

    int s = 5;
    int qtd_vetor[] = new int[s];
    int j = 0;

while (i <= 4) {
            System.out.printf("Inserir o comprimento da telha T%d: ", (i + 1));
            comprimento_vetor[i] = sc.nextInt();
            if (i > 4) {
                break;
            } else {
            System.out.printf("Gostaria de inserir nova telha? S / N: ");
            String confirmacao_telha = sc.next();
            char letra = confirmacao_telha.charAt(0);
            if (letra == 'S') {
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.printf(
                            "--------%n" 
                            + "Comprimentos:%n" 
                            + "T1: %d%n" 
                            + "T2: %d%n" 
                            + "T3: %d%n" 
                            + "T4: %d%n"
                            + "T5: %d%n" 
                            + "--------%n",
                        comprimento_vetor[0], comprimento_vetor[1], 
                        comprimento_vetor[2], comprimento_vetor[3],
                        comprimento_vetor[4]);

                while (j <= 4) {
                    System.out.printf("Inserir a quantidade da telha T%d: ", (p + 1));
                    qtd_vetor[p] = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.printf("Gostaria de inserir nova quantidade? S / N: ");
                    String confirmacao_qtd = sc.next(); 
                    char letra1 = confirmacao_qtd.charAt(0);
                    if (letra1 == 'S') {
                        j++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.printf(
                                "--------%n" 
                                + "Quantidades:%n" 
                                + "T1: %d%n" 
                                + "T2: %d%n" 
                                + "T3: %d%n" 
                                + "T4: %d%n"
                                + "T5: %d%n" 
                                + "--------%n",
                            qtd_vetor[0], qtd_vetor[1], 
                            qtd_vetor[2], qtd_vetor[3],
                            qtd_vetor[4]);
                        break;
                    }       
                }
```

Comment: E qual é a dúvida / o problema?

Comment: Gostaria de saber como implementar o código de multiplicação das posições dos vetores que comentei no inicio do texto, tentei contextualizar demais acredito o que eu estava implementando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiplicação de vetores:**

```
int ixj[] = new int[5]; //Declaração do vetor para armazenar multiplicação dos vetores.

for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){ //5 é o tamanho da alocação do vetor.
    ixj[k] = i[k] * j[k]; //Multiplicação dos vetores, k é a posição dos vetores, fazendo com que faça a operação nas posições 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4.
}
```

**Somatório de vetores:**

```
int ij = 0; //Declaração do inteiro para armazenar somatório dos vetores. Lembre-se de declarar 0 como valor inicial.

for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){ //5 é o tamanho da alocação do vetor.
    ij = ij + ixj[k];
}
```

Outro forma de fazer:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){ //5 é o tamanho da alocação do vetor.
    ij += ixj[k];
}
```

**Multiplicação e somatório na mesma estrutura:**

```
int ixj[] = new int[5], ij = 0, k;

for (k = 0; k < 5; k++){
    ixj[k] = i[k] * j[k];
    ij += ixj[k];
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Acredito que vou conseguir implementar isto, era basicamente o que eu estava procurando. Agradeço!

Comment: Existe como resolver este problema? Quando implementa:

Main.java:80: error: array required, but int found
          ixj[k] = i[k] * j[k];
                    ^
Main.java:80: error: array required, but int found
          ixj[k] = i[k] * j[k];

Comment: O problema está na declaração de objetos da array. Foi corrigido na resposta, onde o erro é a falta dos colchetes ([]).